# Using git on os x 10.10 with samba

Tags: linux, samba, git

We have a development environment set up where we have two local machines (Macs with osx 10.10) and a linux box (Dev server) running ubuntu 14.4.

Samba has been set up in order to share files between local and dev server, we have installed git and it seems to work fine until we revert any of our commits.

This is where we get `.smbdelete` files that are created and then git sees that file and asks us to commit that, we have added `.smb*` to `.gitignore`.

However the files are still being created and whenever we want to revert changes in the future we will just get these files which in time will just stack up.

Does anybody have this kind of set up working fine?

Comment: Why are you using git on a shared fs? That is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Why would it be a disaster?

Comment: Git is meant to be operated on by a single git command at a time, and on s shared filesystem, you have no way of ensuring that. Additionally git is *designed* to be decentralized. There's plain no good reason that you need to introduce additional layers of instability by putting it on a shared drive. Doing so is just asking for repo corruption.

Comment: Okay, we've set this up incorrectly. We won't use the linux box as a file server but we will use this as a staging server and edit files locally. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Yep, devs should edit files locally, commit to their own local copy of the git repo, and then push to a centralized location.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30620/discussion-between-alex-turner-and-eeaa).